# looking for some noun classification model

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, categorization

all. Recently I am thinking about how to put words into a category or some kind when I am learning NLP. For example, if I try to teach computer understand 'apple', I will also want it understand that 'apple' belongs to 'fruit', so that it will learn that 'fruit tree' and understand something like:

```
   fruit
     /\----
    /  \   \
apple  kiwi  pear
```

and this will be useful even when I want to teach something like:
cars are a kind of means of transport, and so some other transports include: motorbikes, airplane and so on.

Anyone knows if I can find some papers or demos working on this kind? Thanks.

Andes

Answer (score 0):

WordNet from Princeton includes some classification information for nouns. I'd recommend the RDF format of the database which you can use to explore what relationships it does have (and which it is missing).

For example:

[image]

Whilst WordNet can map meanings to each other the harder issue you will face is how you determine the meaning of a word in context first. For example is "apple" a tree or a fruit?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, SKOS (Simple Knowledge Organization System) is well suited for this. It is a specialized semantic langage derivated from RDF.

There are many "big" datasets as UNESCO Thesaurus (EN/RU/FR/ES), BNF Thesaurus (FR), ... These are only example among many others

[Link to documentation of SKOS](https://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/)

Comment: Thanks,Gilles. Will try this then! :D